# How do I access a javascript library file from my node_modules to my files in views

Tags: node.js

I am trying to access a javascript library file file from index.ejs.I have written a path this way in index.ejs:

`<script src="../../node_modules/sweetalert/dist/sweetalert.min.js"></script>`

But it is not working. I get an error saying `cannot GET the resource`. 
file structure below:

```
mainapp
|
|_ _ node_module -- sweetalert(folder) -- dist(folder) - -sweetalert.min.js
|
|
|_ _ views-- items(folder) -- index.ejs
```

the documentation says to use lib directory if on new version. I tried both as they suggested and I still get same error.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using Express.js then configure like the below code in app.js file

```
 app.use("/lib", express.static(path.join(__dirname,'node_modules')));
```

Here, lib is the base path and then import this file under the node_modules as below

```
 <script src="/lib/sweetalert/dist/sweetalert.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

Be careful while adding the your file paht under the node_modules folder

Comment: Thank you. I am still working on other aspects of this project. So I did not select any answer. Once I fix things I will get back to you.

Comment: I know this was written a year about but this answer is working. You just need to define `path` like so `var path = require("path");` for it to work without any errors.

Answer (score 0):

Put "sweetalert.min.js" into a "public" folder that is being hosted by your app, nginx, apache, etc...  If you are hosting it from you app (which means you are using pure node.js, express.js, hapi.js, etc...) make sure you have the "public" folder hosted at the "/public" route or something similar.

Then when you need to access it, you can pull it from "*your_domain*/public/sweetalert.min.js".  You can also make a "/scripts" subdirectory of the "/public" folder.